# Database distribution according to CAP

Tags: database, cap-theorem

Does anyone know of a good (hopefully graphical) distribution of popular databases according to the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).
Something like MySQL is more consistent, but less partition tolerant or Redis is more available and partition tolerant, but less consistent and etc.

Ideally an overlay of databases over the CAP Venn diagram would be best, but an article, book or any comparison is also great.

Answer (score 0):

One example/ proof can be found here :
http://architects.dzone.com/articles/better-explaining-cap-theorem